# Capture strings NOT enclosed by balanced parentheses in Lua

Tags: string, lua

Lua patterns include `%b()` and the like to capture strings enclosed by paired strings (in this case, parentheses). However, what if I want to capture everything except `"%b()"`?

What I've tried:

```lua
str = "A time ago (hello)"
string.gsub(str, "[^%b()]", "a")
```

But the result is `aaaaaaaaaaa(aaaaa)`, i.e., it replaces everything except paired parentheses. What I want to get is `aaaaaaaaaaa(hello)` instead.

### Edit

For more context, what I want is to make the following

```lua
myfunction("A nice (house) on an (island)")
--should ignore (house) and (island)
--should work like string.gsub(str, "%w+", "bla"), for instance
--by ignoring enclosed strings
bla bla (house) bla bla (island)
```

Comment: I am not certain Lua can invert `%b()` at all. Probably because a truly inverted `%b()` would not match everything outside of parenthesis, but every string without balanced parenthesis. When you write your charset `[^%b()]`, Lua is skipping the %b and matching any character that is not `(` or `)`. That is why it is printing `aaaaaaaaaaa(aaaaa)`. I was unable to come up with a good pattern as an answer for the problem. Perhaps someone else will.

Comment: It would also help if you gave an exact, real use case - there may be a better solution to your problem than an inverted balance check.

Comment: @lhf I've edited my question for a more specific example. I don't want to remove the enclosed strings, but ignore them when a string function is applied, such as `gsub` or `gmatch`

Comment: Wow. That's exactly what I wanted. Btw, I didn't know it was possible to embed an string function into another. Nice to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
s="A nice (house) on an (island)"
print(s:gsub("(.-)(%b())",function (a,b) return a:gsub("%w+","bla")..b end))
```

This works, except that it does not handle the words after the last parentheses. The solution is to make sure that the input is uniform:

```
s="A nice (house) on an (island) in the Pacific" .. "()" -- here!
print(s:gsub("(.-)(%b())",function (a,b) return a:gsub("%w+","bla")..b end))
```

and then remove the trailing `()` in the output.

Comment: It works even if there are no substrings in parentheses, in which case it does nothing.